# How to add js code to different appended elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have this code (snippet). If you type your name, it will add it below automatically.

If you click "Add member" and type a name inside the appended input, it appears below too (on its respective "Hello, ...")

If you do it again, this time won't work, because the jscode only applies to the first appended elements.

**My question is**: how do I apply this jscode with with a third or fourth member, and so on?

PS. Another question: how do I make it unable to remove the first input text (so it is required to have at least 1 member)?

```js
var name1 = document.getElementById('first');
name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var result = document.querySelector('span.one');
    result.innerHTML = this.value;
});

$('.add').click(function() {
    $('.block:last').after('<div class="block"><input type="text" id="X"><span class="remove">Remove member</span><br><br></div>');
    $('.hello:last').after('<div class="hello">Hello, <span class="name"></span><br><br></div>');
    var name1 = document.getElementById('X');
    name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var result = document.querySelector('span.name');
        result.innerHTML = this.value;
    });
});

$('.optionBox').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('.hello:last').remove();
});
```

```css
.block {
    display: block;
}
input {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
span.add, span.remove {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionBox">

    <div class="block">
        <span class="add">Add member</span>
       <br><br>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" id="first"> <span class="remove">Remove member</span><br><br>
    </div>


</div>

<div class="newmember">

</div>

<br>

<div class="hello">

Hello, <span class="one"></span><br><br>

</div>
```

Comment: BTW, id should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a bit of workout for you. Please check it. I think this is what you are looking for. I am adding same id and class attr for the input and the div to display the content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div class ="' + x + '" ><input type="text" class= "' + x + '" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
      $('.hello:last').after('<div class="hello" id = "' + x + '"   >Hello, <span class="name"></span><br><br></div>');

      $('input').on('input', function(e) {

        divtoappend = $(this).attr('class');
        var val = "";
        var val = $(this).val();
        var sel = "#" + divtoappend + " span";
        $(sel).text('');
        $(sel).append(val);
      });

    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    var rem = $(this).parents('div').attr('class');
    $('#' + rem).remove();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  });


});
```

```css
.block {
    display: block;
}
input {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin : 4px;
}
span.add, span.remove {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" class="1" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>

<div class="hello" id="1">

  Hello, <span class="1"></span><br><br>

</div>
```

Comment: Works great! thanks. I just had to add the autocomplete jscode to the first input.

Comment: Hey. I tried to make it work with an additional input. What you type in the second input should be next to the first appended text.  For example: (first input) First Name / (second input) Last Name. So below it would say "Hello, (first name) (last name). Tried adding another var (this time "y" instead of "x" but failed sadly, using id=" ' + y + '"...) inside the "function(e)". How would you do this? I would thank you a lot, man

Comment: Can you please add your code snippet? And please elaborate what functionality you are trying to achieve? Ready to help

Comment: Thanks, man. Here is how I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/JBxnQ/165/  - With the first group of inputs it works fine. With the second (the added one) works but in different lines (because I used different divs, btw ¿how do I make them all in the same line "in the DOM", not only visual? ). With the third one everything is broken, you'll see.  I want to make it everything work like the first group of inputs. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: It can be achieved in different ways. You can work on the first set of default input fields to make it work from the same loop, i haven't change anything on that.

Comment: You saved my day, bro. you're great

Comment: No worries. @Rohalt . Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think we're all over-thinking this:

```
<div>
    <button id="uxAddMember" class="btn btn-primary">Add Member</button> 
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" data-id="1">
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" class="name" id="name" /> <span style="padding-left: 10px;"><button class="btn btn-warning">Remove Member</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<div>
    <span id="uxHello"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var rows = 1;

        $('#uxAddMember').click(function() {
            $('.container').append($('.row').attr('data-id', rows).html());
            rows++;

        });
     });

     $(document).on('keyup', '.name', function() {
        $('#uxHello').html("Hello, " + $(this).val());
     });

</script>
```

That doesn't include your removal functionality, but it takes care of the name output and adding new rows.